# Setting selected value after .ajax() call only works after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set the selected value that I get from Java session while populating the dropdown. In this case I want to select "selectedCtgry" which is also one of the key in the response json object that gets called.

I know there is a race condition. But I can't figure out how to overcome this issue. I have also used .done() attached to the .ajax() function. That way both the success handler and deferred done not work.

Is there any  way I could work around this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // alert("selectedCtgry: "+selectedCtgry);
   var selectedCtgry=document.getElementById("title").value;
   $("#title").one("click", function() {  
    if(selectedCtgry!=null){
                  var d1 = null;
                        $.ajax({
                             url : 'UpdateHelperServlet',
                             data: {title : selectedCtgry}, 
                             type: 'get',                   
                             dataType:'json',
                             async: false,                   
                             success : function(data) {  
                                      var $options = $();
                                      $.each(data,function(key,value) {
              $options = $options.add($('<option/>').attr('value', key).text(value));
                             });
                             $("#title").html($options);
                             alert("typeof key");
                             $("#title").val(selectedCtgry);          

                              });
                        } 
               });
    });
```

Comment: I'm sure you can better format.

Comment: I don't see a race condition.

Comment: Here is the condition reproduced http://jsfiddle.net/Rbgmm/4/

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? I can't seem to understand your exact question! :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
 $.each(data,function(key,value) {

     if(key == selectedValue)
        $('#title').append('<option selected value="'+key+'">'+value'+</option>');
     else
        $('#title').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value'+</option>');
});
```

Comment: hi ahsan do you have any problem with my solution